# C# - Only read first char with Whileloop

Tags: c#, list, text, while-loop, streamreader

I have been searching for about an hour and simply can't find any solutions to this. I want each row from my .txt-file to be added to my list as long as it starts with the same number. The problem lies within "line.Substring(0, 1)" and i dont know how to solve it. Perhaps you understand what i want to acheive.

```
        using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(schedulePathDays))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line.Substring(0, 1) = file.ReadLine()) == thisDay.ToString())
            {
                exercisesRow.Add(line);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why not `string.StartsWith()`?

Comment: line seems to be null...

Comment: `(line.Substring(0, 1) = file.ReadLine())` is wrong. Did you mean `(file.ReadLine().Substring(0, 1))`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter He's calling `line.SubString` before even assigning anything to line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) and then use LINQ to filter:

```
var result = File.ReadLines("yourPath")
                 .Where(line => line.StartsWith("1"));
```

`ReadLines` is *deferred execution* so it can work in large text file.

**Edit:** To map with your code, replace your code with below:

```
exercisesRow = File.ReadLines(schedulePathDays)
                   .Where(line => line.StartsWith(thisDay.ToString()))
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: Im very new to C# and therefor i don't know how to use the code you just posted. Could you post how my code would look with your code included? thanks!

Comment: @ArvinAshrafi Keep in mind, that you shouldn't blindly copy-paste other people's code. Try to understand the code first. For instance: `File` should actually be `file` (lower-case) and `StartWith` should be `StartsWith` (with 's' in between).

Comment: @Nolonar: thanks for pointing out `StartsWith` :), but `File` should not change to `file` since `ReadLines` is static method

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax doesn't make sense. You might want something like:

```
file.ReadLine().Substring(0,1)==thisDay.ToSTring()
```

I think this is what you wanted to write though Cuong Le's answer is probably a lot nicer (except needing parameterisation).

Answer (score 0):

Your `Substring(0,1)` is in the wrong place. It should come after `line` is assigned.

```
//Altnerately: (...).Substring(0,1) instead of (...)[0]
while((line = file.ReadLine())[0] == thisDay.ToString()[0]){
    //code
}
```

It makes no sense to ask try to assign the result of the Substring method.